# phpDoc Ignore Vendor Directories Except Specified Ones

Tags: composer-php, phpdoc, vendor

How do I ignore all the vendor directories except specified ones?

Here's an example of my directories:

```
- polar
    - logs
    - vendor
        - aws
        - composer
        - epickris
        - phpdocumentor
- src
- system
```

I want to ignore all the vendor directories except the `epickris` directory.

Here's an example of my phpDoc configuration:

phpdoc.dist.xml

```
<phpdoc>
    ...
    <files>
        <directory>polar</directory>
        <directory>polar/vendor/epickris</directory>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <directory>system</directory>
        <file>*.php</file>
        <ignore>polar/logs/*</ignore>
        <ignore>polar/vendor/*</ignore>
    </files>
</phpdoc>
```

Answer (score -2):

You may use next not very elegancy, but well-tried approach.

```
<phpdoc>
    ...
    <files>
        <directory>polar</directory>
        <directory>polar/vendor/epickris</directory>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <directory>system</directory>
        <file>*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*/*/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*/*/*/*.php</file>
        <file>polar/vendor/epickris/*/*/*/*/*/*.php</file>
        <ignore>polar/logs/*</ignore>
        <ignore>polar/vendor/*</ignore>
    </files>
</phpdoc>
```

Comment: I'm not going to try this one, looks like it should work, but it's no good having to manually specify the directory levels.

Comment: @KristianMatthews Have you find more elegant way?